# Como abrir vários HTML's e salvar o conteúdo sequencialmente em um txt

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Preciso abrir vários HTML's, obter o texto deles e salvar em um txt de maneira sequencial, mas não sei como fazer isso.

Eu consigo fazer isso com um único HTML, mas preciso fazer isso com vários, e de maneira sequencial. Pois é um *epub* e preciso que o texto esteja na ordem correta.

Segue meu código:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
arquivo = open('pfv.txt', 'w')
html = open(("index_split_001.html"), encoding="utf8").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
link =  soup.get_text()

arquivo.writelines(link)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeira coisa, as URLS do HTML são padrões? Se sim crie um laço for para ir abrindo todos os arquivos. Caso não seja será necessário você passar como parametro o nome da página. Uma dica caso sejam diversas páginas crie um arquivo .txt com todas as pastas e crie um laço FOR para ler esse .txt com site e ir abrindo cada um deles. Sua lógica está correta agora é necessário apenas percorrer todos os arquivos html

Comment: Nicolas,são arquivos locais mesmo. Os nomes eu posso renomear e usar qualquer um. Deixa eu ver se te entendi. Fazer um for abrindo todas os htmls e a cada abertura escrever no txt? Como eu garanto que que o que já foi escrito não será sobrescrito pelo proximo html?

Comment: No arquivo txt quando inserir você usa quebra de linha, assim ele não vai sobrescrever a mesma linha! Dê uma olhada neste link http://www.devfuria.com.br/python/manipulando-arquivos-de-texto/

Comment: Obrigada cara, ajudou muito.